# How to make smbutil display permissions for the listed shares?

Tags: networking, mount, samba

Since macOS has deprecated `smbclient` in favor of `smbutil`, I've started using it.

However, I cannot get `smbutil` to list the permissions for shared listed using the `view` subcommand.

How can I list the permissions e.g. `READ/WRITE`, so that I know which shares can be properly mounted.

Currently, I could mount the `general` share below without problems, but the `Files` share fails:

```
Nicolass-MacBook-Pro:tmp nlykkei$ mount -t smbfs //guest:@10.10.10.123/Files /tmp/smb
mount_smbfs: mount error: /private/tmp/smb: Unknown error: -1073741275
```

Any ideas?

```
Nicolass-MacBook-Pro:smb nlykkei$ smbutil view -a //10.10.10.123
Share                                           Type    Comments
-------------------------------
print$                                          Disk    Printer Drivers
Development                                     Disk    FriendZone Samba Server Files
IPC$                                            Pipe    IPC Service (FriendZone server (Samba, Ubuntu))
general                                         Disk    FriendZone Samba Server Files
Files                                           Disk    FriendZone Samba Server Files /etc/Files
```